# Adobe Flash Player 11.4 installer is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: windows-7, adobe-flash

I'm installing Adobe Flash Player 11. While installing an error is shown:

> flashplayer_11_ax_debug.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you've downloaded the correct installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 64-bit system, you need to download and install the [64-bit version of Adobe Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

In case your system isn't detected, you can [select the version here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/).